# self healing SQL table possible?

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have this database that (simplified) looks something like this:

```
|id |index_minus|timestamp    |date_time          |year|month|day|hour|minute|close |close_delta|
|---|-----------|-------------|-------------------|----|-----|---|----|------|------|-----------|
|720|719        |1623927699799|Jun 17, 2021, 13:01|2021|6    |17 |13  |1     |18.826|0.00186259 |
|719|718        |1623927671112|Jun 17, 2021, 13:01|2021|6    |17 |13  |1     |18.791|0.00234704 |
|718|717        |1623927578768|Jun 17, 2021, 12:59|2021|6    |17 |12  |59    |18.747|0.00283513 |
|717|716        |1623927502411|Jun 17, 2021, 12:58|2021|6    |17 |12  |58    |18.694|-0.00431425|
|716|715        |1623927394830|Jun 17, 2021, 12:56|2021|6    |17 |12  |56    |18.775|-0.00498172|
|715|714        |1623927247817|Jun 17, 2021, 12:54|2021|6    |17 |12  |54    |18.869|0.00500666 |
|714|713        |1623927162901|Jun 17, 2021, 12:52|2021|6    |17 |12  |52    |18.775|-0.00355589|
|713|712        |1623927061556|Jun 17, 2021, 12:51|2021|6    |17 |12  |51    |18.842|-0.00084845|
|712|711        |1623926351844|Jun 17, 2021, 12:39|2021|6    |17 |12  |39    |18.858|-0.00227501|
|711|710        |1623925750381|Jun 17, 2021, 12:29|2021|6    |17 |12  |29    |18.901|0.00010583 |
|710|709        |1623925450914|Jun 17, 2021, 12:24|2021|6    |17 |12  |24    |18.899|-0.0012683 |
|709|708        |1623925150842|Jun 17, 2021, 12:19|2021|6    |17 |12  |19    |18.923|0.00068747 |
|708|707        |1623924850663|Jun 17, 2021, 12:14|2021|6    |17 |12  |14    |18.91 |0.0030766  |
```

(it goes all the way down to id = 1)
the table gets updated every 5 mins with fresh data. Sometimes, due to connectivity issues, I have  rows of bad data that cause all sorts of problems down the line.
I have included the TWO kinds of bad data cases I can get at id = 715 & id = 710 in this example here: (I dont normally get both of these cases at the same time. I have added both to this example for illustration)

```
|id |index_minus|timestamp    |date_time          |year|month|day|hour|minute|close |close_delta|
|---|-----------|-------------|-------------------|----|-----|---|----|------|------|-----------|
|720|719        |1623927699799|Jun 17, 2021, 13:01|2021|6    |17 |13  |1     |18.826|0.00186259 |
|719|718        |1623927671112|Jun 17, 2021, 13:01|2021|6    |17 |13  |1     |18.791|0.00234704 |
|718|717        |1623927578768|Jun 17, 2021, 12:59|2021|6    |17 |12  |59    |18.747|0.00283513 |
|717|716        |1623927502411|Jun 17, 2021, 12:58|2021|6    |17 |12  |58    |18.694|-0.00431425|
|716|715        |1623927394830|Jun 17, 2021, 12:56|2021|6    |17 |12  |56    |18.775|-0.00498172|
|715|714        |NULL         |NULL               |NULL|NULL |NULL|NULL|NULL |NULL  |NULL       |
|714|713        |1623927162901|Jun 17, 2021, 12:52|2021|6    |17 |12  |52    |18.775|-0.00355589|
|713|712        |1623927061556|Jun 17, 2021, 12:51|2021|6    |17 |12  |51    |18.842|-0.00084845|
|712|711        |1623926351844|Jun 17, 2021, 12:39|2021|6    |17 |12  |39    |18.858|-0.00227501|
|711|710        |1623925750381|Jun 17, 2021, 12:29|2021|6    |17 |12  |29    |18.901|0.00010583 |
|710|709        |1623925450914|DEFAULT            |1   |1    |1  |1   |1     |1     |0          |
|709|708        |1623925150842|Jun 17, 2021, 12:19|2021|6    |17 |12  |19    |18.923|0.00068747 |
|708|707        |1623924850663|Jun 17, 2021, 12:14|2021|6    |17 |12  |14    |18.91 |0.0030766  |
```

so far, I had to wait 2 hours for the data to slowly build up again. It would be super convenient, to have the table to self heal with a single SQL expression.
All I need for this to function is to have continuous numbers in the "close" column.

I would like to search the table for these data gaps. Then update the missing "close" value with the value from the previous row.

the result would look like this:

```
|id |index_minus|timestamp    |date_time          |year|month|day|hour|minute|close |close_delta|
|---|-----------|-------------|-------------------|----|-----|---|----|------|------|-----------|
|720|719        |1623927699799|Jun 17, 2021, 13:01|2021|6    |17 |13  |1     |18.826|0.00186259 |
|719|718        |1623927671112|Jun 17, 2021, 13:01|2021|6    |17 |13  |1     |18.791|0.00234704 |
|718|717        |1623927578768|Jun 17, 2021, 12:59|2021|6    |17 |12  |59    |18.747|0.00283513 |
|717|716        |1623927502411|Jun 17, 2021, 12:58|2021|6    |17 |12  |58    |18.694|-0.00431425|
|716|715        |1623927394830|Jun 17, 2021, 12:56|2021|6    |17 |12  |56    |18.775|-0.00498172|
|715|714        |NULL         |NULL               |NULL|NULL |NULL|NULL|NULL |18.775|NULL       |
|714|713        |1623927162901|Jun 17, 2021, 12:52|2021|6    |17 |12  |52    |18.775|-0.00355589|
|713|712        |1623927061556|Jun 17, 2021, 12:51|2021|6    |17 |12  |51    |18.842|-0.00084845|
|712|711        |1623926351844|Jun 17, 2021, 12:39|2021|6    |17 |12  |39    |18.858|-0.00227501|
|711|710        |1623925750381|Jun 17, 2021, 12:29|2021|6    |17 |12  |29    |18.901|0.00010583 |
|710|709        |1623925450914|DEFAULT            |1   |1    |1  |1   |1     |18.923|0          |
|709|708        |1623925150842|Jun 17, 2021, 12:19|2021|6    |17 |12  |19    |18.923|0.00068747 |
|708|707        |1623924850663|Jun 17, 2021, 12:14|2021|6    |17 |12  |14    |18.91 |0.0030766  |
```

could anyone tell me if this is possible?

Comment: You may also want to normalize the table and get rid of all that date/time portion columns that are dependent of `date_time` to prevent inconsistencies.

Comment: And `index_minus` is analogously problematic.

Comment: I agree, the table could be in itself optimized. But the workflow, built on this exact table cannot be easily changed. So for the moment I am looking for a way to fill in those `NULL` and `1` value gaps in the close column, whenever I have a data integrity situation. This would help me a lot.

Comment: I sort of know how to start the query:
`UPDATE my_table 
SET close = [here i dont know..]
WHERE timestamp = NULL;`
..sort of?